# Python pygame how to shoot bullets from player

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to get my code to shoot a pygame.rect across the screen from player location.
Right now it shoots but when I let off the space button it doesn't reset the rect. I have it set to change the x coordinate but I want it to reset after I release the space button.

if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        mx_change = -100

can I use event.key == pygame.KEYUP: to reset it somehow?

```
    import pygame #####IMPORTING PYGAME MODULE###########################

    pygame.init() 
    #####INITIALIZINGPYGAME##################################

    gameWindow = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600)) ###Screen Width and 
    Height###

    clock = pygame.time.Clock() ## FRAMES PER SECOND ##

    white = (255,255,255)
    black = (0,0,0)


    def player(px,py):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameWindow,black,[px,py,30,30])

    def missile(mx,my):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameWindow,black,[mx,my,10,10])


    def gameloop():

        px = 700
        py = 300

        mx = 700
        my = 300

        px_change = 0
        py_change = 0

        mx_change = 0
        my_change = 0

        gameExit = False

        while not gameExit:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    gameExit = True
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        mx_change = -10
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        mx_change = 10
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        my_change = -10
                    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        my_change = 10

                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        mx_change = -100


                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        px_change = -10
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        px_change = 10
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        py_change = -10
                    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        py_change = 10

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                px_change = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                py_change = 0

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                mx_change = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                my_change = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                mx_change = 0
                my_change = 0


    px += px_change
    py += py_change

    mx += mx_change
    my += my_change

    gameWindow.fill(white)

    player(px,py)
    missile(mx,my)
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(15)

pygame.quit()
quit()
gameloop()
```

Comment: Pleas proper format the code in the question and respect the [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). `if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:` has to be in the event loop, rather than the main loop. But since all the code in the question seems to be misaligned, it is impossible to distinguish what is a bug in the code and what is caused by pasting the code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this.

When you press Space Key, you launch the missile.It is calculated as `mx_change = -100`
But you press the button at the second time, the missile has never been launched.

Because you forget to rewrite the variable.

```
if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
    mx_change = 0
if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
    my_change = 0
if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
    mx_change = 0
    my_change = 0
```

Certainly, you can change the `mx_change` & `my_change`, but you pass it through `missile` function.That is to say, missile position is decided by `mx` & `my`, as you can see.

So I recommend that you write as follows.

```
mx = px
my = py
```

**Why do I set these points?**

Your missile is black. and player is also black.
Missile is launched from the player. 
The both things are black, so it is very good.

If you have some question, please ask me by comment.

---

```
import pygame #####IMPORTING PYGAME MODULE###########################

pygame.init() 
#####INITIALIZINGPYGAME##################################

gameWindow = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600)) ###Screen Width and Height###

clock = pygame.time.Clock() ## FRAMES PER SECOND ##

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)


def player(px,py):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameWindow,black,[px,py,30,30])

def missile(mx,my):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameWindow,black,[mx,my,10,10])


def gameloop():

    px = 700
    py = 300

    mx = 700
    my = 300

    px_change = 0
    py_change = 0

    mx_change = 0
    my_change = 0

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    mx_change = -10
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    mx_change = 10
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    my_change = -10
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    my_change = 10

                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    mx_change = -100


                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    px_change = -10
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    px_change = 10
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    py_change = -10
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    py_change = 10

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    px_change = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    py_change = 0


                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    mx_change = 0
                    mx = px
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    my_change = 0
                    my = py
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    mx_change = 0
                    my_change = 0
                    mx = px
                    my = py

            px += px_change
            py += py_change

            mx += mx_change
            my += my_change

            gameWindow.fill(white)
            player(px,py)
            missile(mx,my)

            pygame.display.update()

            clock.tick(15)
gameloop()
```